# Shutdown boost threads correctly

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost

I have x boost threads that work at the same time. One producer thread fills a synchronised queue with calculation tasks. The consumer threads pop out tasks and calculates them.

[image: Synchronised Queue]
Image Source: https://www.quantnet.com/threads/c-multithreading-in-boost.10028/

The user may finish the programm during this process, so I need to shutdown my threads properly. My current approach seems to not work, since exceptions are thrown. It's intented that on system shutdown all processes should be killed and stop their current task no matter what they do. Could you please show me, how you would kill thoses threads?

Thread Initialisation:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfThreads; i++)
    {
        std::thread* thread = new std::thread(&MyManager::worker, this);
        mThreads.push_back(thread);
    }
```

Thread Destruction:

```
void MyManager::shutdown()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfThreads; i++)
    {
        mThreads.at(i)->join();
        delete mThreads.at(i);
    }
    mThreads.clear();
}
```

Worker:

```
void MyManager::worker()
{
    while (true)
    {

        int current = waitingList.pop();
        Object * p = objects.at(current);
        p->calculateMesh(); //this task is internally locked by a mutex

        try
        {
            boost::this_thread::interruption_point();
        }
        catch (const boost::thread_interrupted&)
        {
            // Thread interruption request received, break the loop
            std::cout << "- Thread interrupted. Exiting thread." << std::endl;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Synchronised Queue:

```
#include <queue>
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>
#include <condition_variable>

template <typename T>
class ThreadSafeQueue
{
public:

    T pop()
    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> mlock(mutex_);
        while (queue_.empty())
        {
            cond_.wait(mlock);
        }
        auto item = queue_.front();
        queue_.pop();

        return item;
    }

    void push(const T& item)
    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> mlock(mutex_);
        queue_.push(item);
        mlock.unlock();
        cond_.notify_one();
    }


    int sizeIndicator()
    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> mlock(mutex_);
        return queue_.size();
    }


private:

    bool isEmpty() {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> mlock(mutex_);
        return queue_.empty();
    }

    std::queue<T> queue_;
    std::mutex mutex_;
    std::condition_variable cond_;
};
```

The thrown error call stack:

```
... std::_Mtx_lockX(_Mtx_internal_imp_t * * _Mtx) Line 68   C++
... std::_Mutex_base::lock() Line 42    C++
... std::unique_lock<std::mutex>::unique_lock<std::mutex>(std::mutex & _Mtx) Line 220   C++
... ThreadSafeQueue<int>::pop() Line 13 C++
... MyManager::worker() Zeile 178   C++
```

Comment: Two things: isEmpty is not locked, and size() could have a simpler implementation: after mutex is locked you could simply return queue_.size() (and mlock destructor releases the mutex)

Comment: @marom thanks, corrected my code. The error is still there.

Comment: Two things: isEmpty and size may not be public. Whatever they report may be invalid when evaluated by the caller. Unless they are used privately they shall be removed.

Comment: A member like size can make sense if you want to give just an indication of the work in progress (e.g. a progress bar)

Comment: @marom: If it is there, it is a pitfall and someone WILL get trapped. Is it required? If not - delete it, definitely. If required as indicator - I would at least name it differently and even return a different type (e.g. predfined watermarks).

Comment: @stefan you are right. I changed the code. I use the sizeIndicator currently just for debugging. To make visible if the size is not increasing to infinity. I plan to dynamically change the calculation based on the waitinglist size.

Comment: I think the `ThreadSafeQueue` object destroyed before threads finished their work. Make sure that `ThreadSafeQueue` object destroyed after all workers destroyed and no new workers started after `ThreadSafeQueue` destroyed.

Comment: @gomons and how can I make sure that all wokers are destroyed? I assumed that I do this by Interrupt() and join() as written in code.

Comment: @Anthea, try to create `ThreadSafeQueue` object in `shared_ptr` and pass that `shared_ptr` in every thread function. this ensures that `ThreadSafeQueue` object exists while threads exist. For test purpose only. Maybe it is not issue here.

Comment: It's quite likely that the code you're interrupting isn't safe to interrupt at all its interruption points.

Comment: You seem to have a recent C++ compiler (`auto` and `std::mutex` suggest that). So why are you using Boost's threads istead of `std::thread`? I think their syntax is mostly equivalent, so converting isn't difficult. Still, extract a minimal example that demonstrates the issue. As it stands, there is both too much and too little code.

Comment: changed to std::thread. trying to offer a smaller code sample.

Comment: Some comments and answers are already there. Summing up: You should interrupt all threads, then join all of them and finally delete the thread objects and the queue. your threads do not need interruption points as they sleep in the push/pop functions. the try block must enclose the push/pop call to catch the interrupded exception.

Comment: How and when is the queue created/destroyed.  The crash stack looks like it is a thread, but is behaving like the queue no longer exists

Comment: I wouldn't expect the boost::this_thread::interruption_point stuff to work with std::thread, btw; if you really want to switch it to std::thread, you'll probably also need to change how something waiting in pop() gets woken up.

Answer (score 3):

From my experience on working with threads in both Boost and Java, trying to shut down threads externally is always messy. I've never been able to really get that to work cleanly.

The best I've gotten is to have a boolean value available to all the consumer threads that is set to true. When you set it to false, the threads will simply return on their own. In your case, that could easily be put into the while loop you have.

On top of that, you're going to need some synchronization so that you can wait for the threads to return before you delete them, otherwise you can get some hard to define behavior.

An example from a past project of mine:

Thread creation

```
barrier = new boost::barrier(numOfThreads + 1);
threads = new detail::updater_thread*[numOfThreads];

for (unsigned int t = 0; t < numOfThreads; t++) {
    //This object is just a wrapper class for the boost thread.
    threads[t] = new detail::updater_thread(barrier, this);
}
```

Thread destruction

```
for (unsigned int i = 0; i < numOfThreads; i++) {
    threads[i]->requestStop();//Notify all threads to stop.
}

barrier->wait();//The update request will allow the threads to get the message to shutdown.

for (unsigned int i = 0; i < numOfThreads; i++) {
    threads[i]->waitForStop();//Wait for all threads to stop.
    delete threads[i];//Now we are safe to clean up.
}
```

Some methods that may be of interest from the thread wrapper.

```
//Constructor
updater_thread::updater_thread(boost::barrier * barrier)
{
   this->barrier = barrier;
   running = true;

   thread = boost::thread(&updater_thread::run, this);
}

void updater_thread::run() {
    while (running) {
        barrier->wait();
        if (!running) break;

        //Do stuff

        barrier->wait();
    }
}

void updater_thread::requestStop() {
    running = false;
}

void updater_thread::waitForStop() {
    thread.join();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try moving 'try' up (like in the sample below). If your thread is waiting for data (inside waitingList.pop()) then may be waiting inside the condition variable .wait(). This is an 'interruption point' and so may throw when the thread gets interrupted.

```
void MyManager::worker()
{
    while (true)
    {
        try
        {
            int current = waitingList.pop();
            Object * p = objects.at(current);
            p->calculateMesh(); //this task is internally locked by a mutex

            boost::this_thread::interruption_point();
        }
        catch (const boost::thread_interrupted&)
        {
            // Thread interruption request received, break the loop
            std::cout << "- Thread interrupted. Exiting thread." << std::endl;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: tried it, but the error is still there. I am updating the question with the debug call list of the crash.

Comment: I'd wrap the whole loop into a try-catch-clause. It won't change anything here, but the very point of exceptions is that they travel through all control flow structures like loops, so that you don't have to do that manually.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are catching the wrong exception class? 
Which would mean it does not get caught.
Not too familiar with threads but is it the mix of std::threads and boost::threads that is causing this?

Try catching the lowest parent exception.

Answer (score -2):

I think this is a classic problem of reader/writer thread working on a common buffer. One of the most secured way of working out this problem is to use mutexes and signals.( I am not able to post the code here. Please send me an email, I post the code to you).